# Passing variables into Handlebars template when rendering Marionette/Backbone View

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

I'm using Handlebars with Backbone and Marionette.  I'm compiling my Handlebars templates and storing them in an object that can be referenced by the view definitions.  I'm using a LayoutView and regions to display the various items I need in the UI.

What I want to do is pass (boolean) variables into the view such that Handlebars will make decisions (via block helper `{{#if varName}}`) about what to render.  For clarity I don't want to persist this data so I'd really rather not make them part of the model that I'm passing in to be rendered.

So what I'm doing is defining a Backbone.Model and a Marionette.ItemView as normal, and trying to pass in additional variables via initialize:

```
var newUser = new app.UserView({
  model: new app.UserModel(),
  initialize: function(){
    this.isNewDoc = true
  }
});
// display the view in a region using app.regions.maun.show(newUser);
// ...etc.
```

What I want is to be able to pass in and be able to refer to variables such as `isNewDoc` in the Handlebars template, ideally via `{{#if isNewDoc}}...{{/if}}`.

I've tried various permutations for line `this.isNewDoc = true` such as `isNewDoc: true` but I'm not getting anywhere.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I override the serializeData method when I want to do this. You can also do it by overriding the toJSON method in the model, but as you mention then it will get sent to the server when you persist the model. Since these are calculated attributes and not persistent attributes, then I don't like sending them to the server. An example is below:

```
var newUser = new app.UserView({

  model: new app.UserModel(),

  serializeData: function() {
    return _.extend({
      isNewDoc: true
    }, this.model.toJSON());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tyler Marien, I tested that and, maybe it works well for a vanilla Backbone.View, but for a Marionette.ItemView it didn't :(

However your suggestion started me looking into methods on a Marionette.ItemView called `serializeData` and then the idea of serializing data is general, and that in turn took me back to the Marionette documentation.  Which I probably should have read more carefully in the first place :)

The good news is that View.templateHelpers seem to do exactly what I want - check out http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.view.html#viewtemplatehelpers - and View.mergeOptions also seem applicable.  My key takeaway: remember to RTFM.

Comment: serializeData is a method specific to [Marionette.ItemView](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.itemview.html#itemview-serializedata) so it will definitely work. templateHelpers might be a better solution for what you are doing though and not something I have used much so thanks for pointing it out.